# How to show no other elements besides $\pm 1$ will be in the kernel of $h: \mathbb Z_p^* \rightarrow \mathbb Z_p^*$; $h(\bar{a}) = \bar{a}^2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, congruences

Let $p$ be a prime and let $h: \mathbb Z_p^* \rightarrow \mathbb Z_p^*$ be defined by $h(\overline{a}) = \overline{a}^2$.

Since $h(\overline{xy}) = \overline{xy}^2 = \overline{x}^2 \overline{y}^2 = h(\overline{x}) h(\overline{y})$, $h$ is a homomorphism.  Now, we can see that the kernel of $h$ will include $\pm \overline{1}$.

> Now, I am having trouble trying to formally show that no other elements will be in the kernal. I am trying to show that if $a$ is any other element besides $\pm \overline{1}$, then $a \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.  We can see this through examples but I'm not sure how to show in general.

Comment: Consider the congruence $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. This can be rewritten as $(x-1)(x+1)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Because $p$ is prime, $p$ divides $(x-1)(x+1)$ if and only if $p$ divides $x-1$ or $p$ divides $x+1$. The first gives $x\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and the second gives $x\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbf Z_p$ is a field, and in a field, a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots.

Answer (score 2):

If $a^2\equiv 1$ then $p|a^2-1$. So by Euclid $p|a+1$ or $p|a-1$. So $a \equiv \pm1\bmod p$

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z_p^*$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group on $p-1$ elements. Since $p-1$ is even and there are clearly at most two solutions to
$$x+x\equiv 0\pmod{2n}$$
it follows that there are at most two solutions to
$$x\cdot x\equiv 1\pmod p$$

Comment: Why $\pmod{2n}$?

Comment: @JohannFranklin I put that to emphasize that there are only (exactly) two solutions mod an even number (so we're taking $2n=p-1$ implicitly, and representing the cyclic group on $p-1$ elements as the elements mod $2n$)